# Merging two tables together where all columns don't match

Tags: mysql

I am trying to put these two tables together:

Orders

```
id  positionID  Quantity
1   1           1
2   1           1
3   2           2
4   3           1
```

Positions

```
id  month   year    position    available   max
1   1       2017    Header      0           2
2   1       2017    Footer      0           2
3   2       2017    Header      1           2
4   2       2017    Footer      2           2
```

The positionId column in Orders references the id in positions. I know to get those two together I need a JOIN ON statement on the foreign key value, no problem there. But I would also like to include rows directly from the position table. This is where I'm lost. The main purpose of this is to get positions where an order has not been created(like the last row in the example output).

The output I'm looking for is this:

```
orderID month   year    position    quantity    available   max
1       1       2017    Header      1           0           2
2       1       2017    Header      1           0           2
        1       2017    Header                  0           2
3       2       2017    Footer      2           0           2
        2       2017    Footer                  0           2
4       2       2017    Header      1           1           2
        2       2017    Header                  1           2
        2       2017    Footer                  2           2
```

Comment: Here is how to: http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_join_right.asp or http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_join_full.asp

Comment: Why does your expected result contain one addition row for each Positions?

Comment: select o.id as orderId, p.month, p.year, p.position, o.quantity, p.available, p.max from order o left join position p on o.positionId = p.id order by o.id asc; p.id asc

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @donlys Professional rivalry no doubt, but see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource

Comment: @Strawberry - wow! didn't know that - thanks for pointing it out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query delivers the requested output:

```
SELECT NULL AS orderId, `month`, `year`, position, NULL AS quantity, 
       available, `max`, id
FROM Positions

UNION ALL

SELECT o.id AS orderId, p.`month`, p.`year`, p.position, o.quantity, 
       p.available, p.`max`, p.id AS id
FROM Orders o 
INNER JOIN Positions p on o.positionId = p.id 
ORDER BY id, CASE WHEN orderId IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, position
```